# if x > y not working where x is greater than y python 2.7

Tags: linux, python-2.7, terminal

I'm trying to make a game on the Linux terminal w/o pygame and curses. I made a function called `readlevels()` and at line 36 and 39, a bug appeared. That part of the program is to make sure all the levels fit in the terminal. I even used `print` to make sure the variables were the right ones. Anyone have any idea why it does not work? I'm using python 2.7 and the levels were stored in a .txt file, but I doubt that would help.

```
import sys, os, time
def readlevels():
        #Open level file
        levelfile = 'levels.txt' #file with all the levels
        try:
                leveltxt = open(levelfile, 'r')
        except IOError:
                return str('The file ' + levelfile + ' is not in this directory. Please look for a file with the levels and name  it' +levelfile + ' before continuing the game. This file is needed to store all of the levels$
        #Read level file
        levels = []
        currentlevel = []
        for line in leveltxt.readlines():
                if ';' in line: #lines with ';' will be ignored
                        pass
                elif '~' in line: #lines with '~' will seperate levels (also show level number)
                        levels.append(currentlevel)
                        currentlevel = []
                else: #all other lines are part of the level
                        currentlevel.append(line)
        #Make Necessary adjustments in the list 'levels' and make the cleaner list 'levels2'
        levels = levels[1:] #gets rid of the [] at the beginning of 'levels' (bug fix)
        levels2 = []
        for level in levels:
                level2 = [] #not to be confused with 'levels2' which has an 's'. This replaces all items in 'levels' while 'levels2' replaces the entire list
                for line in level:
                        level2.append(line.rstrip())
                levels2.append(level2)
        #Overwrite 'levels' with 'levels2' so it does not look weird for the rest of the program
        levels = levels2
        #Checks to see if all levels will fit on the terminal
        terminalsize = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split() #terminalsize[0] is rows in terminal, terminalsize[1] is letters per row
        print terminalsize
        levelnum = 1 #level number
        for level in levels: #level is now each level again
                print len(level), terminalsize[0] #this was to check if len(level) and terminalsize[0] was the number I wanted
                if len(level) > terminalsize[0]: #if level has more rows than the terminal
                        return str('Level ' + levelnum + ' is too big for the terminal. Easily fixable by increasing the size of the terminal or decreasing the font size, or deleting/changing the level')
                for line in level:
                        if len(line) > terminalsize[1]: #if level is too wide for the terminal
                                return str('Level ' + levelnum  + ' is too big for the terminal. Easily fixable by increasing the size of the terminal, decreasing the font size, or deleting/changing the level')
                levelnum += 1
        #Finish
        return levels
print readlevels()
```

The following code is `levels.txt`, but I doubt it helps.

```
-Blocks --------- P
-Enemies -------- A, B, C, D, E
-Exit Block ----- S
-Start Block ---- S




~1 
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                             EEEE                 P
P                             E  E                 P
P                             E  E                 P
P                             EEEE                 P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                                                  P
P                          S                       P
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP                                                               

~2
- TO BE CONTD
```

'Readlevels' normally returns a list of all the levels, and each level in the list is another list of all the lines in that level.

Comment: What's line 36? What's line 39?

Comment: The part where it checks if the level fits in the terminal. I said that on the top of the question. Line 36 is `if len(level) > terminalsize[0]:`, line 39 is `if len(line) > terminalsize[1]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are comparing integer with string. Try

`if len(level) > int(terminalsize[0]):`

instead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that terminalsize was a string because when I used `print` to check if the numbers are right, it would not show the quotation marks.